# Using Jquery ScrollTo Plugin how do I select a specific jquery selector ie: find.('element')

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, scrollto

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $(".content").hide();
            $('.more-btn').click(function( e ){
               e.stopPropagation(); // to lower "DOM layers"
               $(this).closest('section').find('.content').show(500, 'swing'), $('body').css('cursor','help'),$.scrollTo('.content', 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );
               $(this).hide();
            });
```

This is working fine, my problem is that I can figure out how to 
select this content path specificallY

```
$(this).closest('section').find('.content')
```

within in this

```
 $.scrollTo('.content', 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );
```

It seems that I can not just use normal selection string while using the scrollTo plugin example

```
 $.scrollTo($(this).closest('section').find('.content'), 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );
```

I feel like using selectors with the plugin requires a different way of writing them correct me if I am wrong?

I should tell you I am trying to scroll to the closest content section depending on which more button is pushed.

html is

```
  <section>
                <article class="toggle-box" id="toggle1">
                    <aside class="info-rollover">
                        <h3>Locavores</h3>
                        <button class="more-btn">Show More</button>
                    </aside>
                </article>
                <aside class="content">
                    <img src="images/loca/1.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/2.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/3.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/4.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/5.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/6.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/7.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/8.jpg"/>
                    <img src="images/loca/9.jpg"/>
                </aside>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Your code works fine:

Instead of this:

```
$.scrollTo('.content', 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );
```

you can use this:

```
$.scrollTo($(this).closest('section').find('.content'), 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );
```

Please see this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/eeLms/

As per your comments, I've added in multiple sections, and click any of the buttons scrolls to the correct section.

mkm

Comment: But with the -50px offset and your current example, you won't see any difference on the screen.  Other than that, your code works fine.

Comment: Hey thanks but I actually want the -50px offset. The problem is that the html for the section is repeated multiple times.  I need the scrollTo to select the aside.content in the corresponding section. and scroll it to the top with -50px offset.  @manishie  I could of pasted more of my code but I thought I was clear enough apparently not.

Comment: ok, i've updated my fiddle and it works per your requirements.  Your original code is fine.

Comment: this assumes I add another class more-btn2, I am unsure how many of these sections there will be and I dont want to add another function each time I add a section.  I appreciate your help.  I said above that I know the original code works.  I guess more than anything I am asking how I use jquery selectors with the scrollTo plug In @manishie

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  When I cleaned up my code to update my answer, I removed the modification I made.  I've put it back in.  Basically, what you were trying to do works: $.scrollTo($(this).closest('section').find('.content'), 800, {offset:-50, easing:'easeInOutBack'} );

Comment: And I had already removed the more-btn2 class previously when I originally updated.

Comment: the functions competete with each other and it does not work.

Comment: maybe you're having a browser specific issue?  on the latest chrome, it's working fine for me.  if i click any of the buttons, it shows that section then jumps to it.  which "functions compete with one another"?

Comment: Imagine if the section was repeated again.  Yes it works for one section but not multiples

Comment: the section is repeated 3 times in the demo.

Comment: click the top button followed by the middle one it does not work. If u click the buttom then the middle then the top it works

Comment: when i click the top button, it does show the correct section.  it just doesn't do a bouncy movement.  is that why you're saying it doesn't work?  it does that because it doesn't need to scroll anywhere.  that's the expected behavior.